# Support multiple package name association using Branch.io

Tags: branch.io

Branch takes care of creating, applying and confirming Android App Links associations when using it. And that's truly great.
However, it comes to be a tricky question where there are a few package names for the same app, as Branch doesn't give an ability to specify few package names in Android setup. Also, it's not possible to upload custom domain associations files.
Have anyone faced it? Please advice.

P.s. The problem is rather a missing feature than a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently [Branch](http://branch.io) doesn't support creating DAL associations files for multiple flavors (package names) of the same app.
I've contacted Branch support and applied a feature request for this so maybe it will be possible in the future releases.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to add multiple package names so that the same link can give the option to open multiple apps. You can achieve this functionality by adding the same URI scheme intent filter and Android App links intent filter to the Android Manifest of all your apps.

```
<!-- Branch URI Scheme -->
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="androidexample" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>

<!-- Branch App Links (optional) -->
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.app.link" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="example-alternate.app.link" />
</intent-filter>
```

If added, whenever a person clicks on the link it will provide to option to open the link via all the apps which can handle the intent. In order to read the link parameters, you can use the same Branch key for all apps.

I am not sure why you need to upload a custom domain associations file. It would be really helpful if you could provide more details about your use case to understand what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. No, the question isn't about deep link configurations on the app side. It's more about inability to support Android App Links that comes with Android 6.0+ (https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html) and connected to Branch Dashboard missed features.

Comment: @sttimchenko Maybe I am not understanding the issue correctly, but Branch links definitely support Android App links. You can follow the guide specified [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#integrate-branch). You just need to update the Branch dashboard with the SHA256 cert and add the App link intent filter to your Manifest. Branch will take care of hosting the Digital Asset Links file for you. Let me know if I am misunderstandinfg your question.

Comment: indeed, it's working, but, using Branch dashboard it's not possible to setup ADL association file for **multiple** flavors (package names) of the same app. Anyway, I've contacted Branch support and applied a feature request so the question is closed. Thank you for your help btw!